# Scala: Map a List of ids to launch future for each

Tags: scala, future

I have a a list of ids in Scala and for each id I launch a future to perform a database operation like below:

```
import myPackage.myExecutionContext

def doDbOperation(ids: List[Long]) = ids.map { id =>
  Future(get(id))
}
```

I notice that the Futures are executed only after the traversal of list is completed (List is pretty large). How do I make the Future to be launched as and when possible (based on available threads) without waiting for the traversal to complete?

Comment: Could it depend on the `ExecutionContext` you're using? Maybe it batches executions?

Comment: @pagoda_5b Nope, the `ExecutionContext` does not do batch executions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `Future.traverse`. Docs say "This is useful for performing a parallel map. For example, to apply a function to all items of a list in parallel".

```
Future.traverse(ids)(id => Future(get(id)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can not explain the observed behavior (Future body not executing until the map traversal has completed). The following will print `Running future while mapping`:

```
package org.example

import scala.concurrent.{ Future }
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Test extends App {

  @volatile var hasStarted = false

  val ids: List[Long] = Range.Long(0L, 100000L, 1L).toList

  val res = ids.map({ id =>
    val res = Future {
      if (!hasStarted) hasStarted = true
      id
    }
    if (hasStarted) println("Running future while mapping")
    res
  })
}
```

Which makes sense; `Future.apply` does not perform differently depending on whether it is called inside a `map` or a `Future.traverse`.

Re: `Future.traverse` The return types are different.

`ids.map { id => Future(get(id)) }` returns `List[Future[DBObject]]`

but

`Future.traverse(ids)(id => Future(get(id)))` returns `Future[List[DBObject]]`

`Future[List[DBObject]]` is almost always more useful but you are changing the semantics (and maybe you don't want to).